# Host-based snakeoil certificates in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, hosts

How to create snakeoil a certificate and a key for a given host in Ubuntu?

Comment: You might find more or better answers on SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 10):

First make sure that the ssl-cert package is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ssl-cert
```

Then, try the command below.

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```

This will end up creating or overwriting the following files:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```